Express nodemailer custom headers not getting set in the email which is being sent to the reciever user
I have a backend application built with Express.js, and I'm using Nodemailer to send emails. I need to set custom headers in the emails so that I can later read my inbox and group those emails according to the headers I have set. However, the custom headers are not being set as intended. Below is the code I am using to send the email and set custom headers.
async function sendEmailMsg(to, subject, message, organizationId, messageId) {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
    secure: true,
    auth: { user: process.env.USER_EMAIL, pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "My From email address here",
    to,
    subject,
    html: message,
    headers: {
      "X-Organization-ID": organizationId,
      "X-Message-ID": messageId,
    },
  };

  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
}

So i need help in this as i need to set these headers when email is being sent as later i would need to group my email on the basis of these headers passed.


Show us where your code  defines custom headers. 2) If you hardcode them, what happens?


Here is the section of my code where I define custom headers using Nodemailer:
"https://i.postimg.cc/q7d4MG4L/image.png" .
Despite hardcoding the headers, they do not appear in the received email. I have also verified the mailOptions object before sending the email, and the headers are included correctly in the object. However, they are not present in the email when it is received.

No, organizationId and messageId are vars. I mean that. Where did you define their content? Add the corresponding code editing the question, not in a comment...
